# jquery convert text to image

Tags: jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My code generated by Yii2 framework give me a text inside label, that text is images url. I tried to convert that text to image using jquery and append but It's not working my code generated by Yii2 is

```
<div id="gallery-gallery_id">
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="176" type="checkbox"> u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png</label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="177" type="checkbox"> u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png</label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="180" type="checkbox"> u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg</label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="178" type="checkbox"> u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png</label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="179" type="checkbox"> u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png</label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="181" type="checkbox"> u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg</label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="182" type="checkbox"> u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg</label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="183" type="checkbox"> u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg</label>
</div>
```

I did

```
<?php foreach ($model->galleries as $image) {?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#gallery-gallery_id label').append('<img src="<?= $image->gallery_lgimage)?>" height="100" width="100">');
</script>
<?php }?>
```

But I get for each label all images, I'm trying to get one image for each label

the result I get

```
<div id="gallery-gallery_id">
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="176" type="checkbox"> 176<img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg" width="100" height="100"></label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="177" type="checkbox"> 177<img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg" width="100" height="100"></label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="178" type="checkbox"> 178<img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg" width="100" height="100"></label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="179" type="checkbox"> 179<img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg" width="100" height="100"></label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="180" type="checkbox"> 180<img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg" width="100" height="100"></label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="181" type="checkbox"> 181<img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg" width="100" height="100"></label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="182" type="checkbox"> 182<img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg" width="100" height="100"></label>
<label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="183" type="checkbox"> 183<img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/114400179a0768d203377245b8654714fe9bb65.1png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/21440017a0fb0bd39d7388fefaae540cb069483.2png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/3144001878d1205735991133700565964c026bd.3png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430400/414400133d68969a6162ea0290cfbb80817852f.4png" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/114421754b47aa61094f6765a7ff76f3f1296cc.1jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/314421752c0c9d277bf133a6ca82992742c080d.3jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/5144217e177430e5b8a11b224bba3470681f34b.5jpg" width="100" height="100"><img src="u-fls/MjQoDMoZ00oNQ742Oa2262018/uQzxuXmLWHQSs3754As/gal//1534430537/7144217b578dfce326513fc927499138447916d.7jpg" width="100" height="100"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I did add the result that I get afer using jquery append

Comment: I suggest writing the HTML content as needed with PHP. Is there a reason you need to use JavaScript?

Comment: no but the checkbox is generated by Yii2 so I just want to show image instead of link, if there is any other solution I will use it

Comment: Can you show how you're generating list of these inputs/labels? I'm pretty sure that this could be fixed at Yii level without involving JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're appending each `<image>` to every `<label>`. `$('#gallery-gallery_id label')` matches all `<label>` elements inside the `#gallery-gallery_id`.

As I understand it, you want to convert the text url in each `<label`> into an `<image>` element inside that `<label`>.

In my method below, I'm looping over each `<label>`, converting its text url into an image element, and appending that `<image>` to the `<label>`. I'm relying on jQuery's [`text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to strip out the HTML and return only the text url.

Although, as I mentioned in my comment above, it might be simpler to use PHP to write out the HTML as you want it, rather than using JavaScript to manipulated it later.

```js
jQuery('#gallery-gallery_id label').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $input = $this.find('input');
  var url = $this.text();
  var $img = jQuery('<img>', {
    'src': url
  });
  $this.html($input).append($img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-gallery_id">
  <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="176" type="checkbox"> https://loremflickr.com/20/20?random=1</label>
  <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="177" type="checkbox"> https://loremflickr.com/20/20?random=2</label>
  <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="180" type="checkbox"> https://loremflickr.com/20/20?random=3</label>
  <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="178" type="checkbox"> https://loremflickr.com/20/20?random=4</label>
  <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="179" type="checkbox"> https://loremflickr.com/20/20?random=5</label>
  <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="181" type="checkbox"> https://loremflickr.com/20/20?random=6</label>
  <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="182" type="checkbox"> https://loremflickr.com/20/20?random=7</label>
  <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="183" type="checkbox"> https://loremflickr.com/20/20?random=8</label>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working but url src it's give the label value it's doesn't give the text : <label><input name="Gallery[gallery_id][]" value="176" type="checkbox"><img src=" 176"></label>

Comment: Are your sure your original code contains the text URLs? In your results, it looks like the text is that numeric value instead of a URL.

Comment: You are right my old javascript code give value; I fixed 
thank you so much

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

Select only one label at a time to append your image to.

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach ($model->galleries as $image) {

    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#gallery-gallery_id label:nth-child(' . $i . ')").append("<img src=\"' . $image->gallery_lgimage . '\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\">);
        </script>';
   $i++;

} ?>
```

Comment: It's almost that but it's not generate the image inside the label, I'm trying to get image inside the label

Comment: Ah. Append the label with the image ;) See my revised answer.

Comment: I'm trying to get it inside the checkbox label, so every checkbox will have it's own image, like in my result just I want to show only the image for that box